# Eelement evaluates correctly in normal(none puppeteer browser) but not in puppeteer browser

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate a button press, the problem, is I always get the "no node found in selector" error I've gotten this working in the past however every time I do a puppeteer project it is luck of the draw with whether or not i can successfully find selectors, I've tried waiting for selector, waiting for the network to go idle, I've tried delaying until page loaded, I've set the screen size to the max so selector is visible on the page.

This is in my browser(chrome)

> eval(document.getElementsByClassName("button"))

result

```
HTMLCollection(2) [a.button, a.button]
0: a.button
1: a.button
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: HTMLCollection
```

this below is in puppeteer chrome browser, I can see the button, the selector in the inspector, and the screen is max, however.

```
eval(document.getElementsByClassName("button"))
```

returns

```
HTMLCollection []length: 0__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

I have been stuck on this for days, I've gotten around it by tabbing my way through to a button, but in this current project I really need to click it directly

Edit: here is the HTML

[The two buttons in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHsRK.png)

Comment: could you provide your HTML and element with which you want to interact, please

Comment: I have gone ahead and added a picture of the two buttons in question